# Sync Services Client and Schema Xcode Project Structure

Tags: cocoa, syncservices, xcode, objective-c

I've started work on a project that will be primarily acting as a Sync Services Client. Ideally, the project have two components: a custom schema bundle and a preference pane.

As a first step, I've created an Xcode project for the schema bundle. But now I found myself ready to start writing the code for the preference pane and the client, and I'm not sure what the best way is to integrate it with the project I already have.

What approaches have you found to work well in these kinds of situations?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is probably to create a new Pref Pane project. That way you get all the benefits. After that, you can actually drag the project into your schema project and make it a dependent of your schema project. Whenever you build your main project (the schema project), if there are any changes in your pref pane project it will get rebuilt.